# overwrite -moz-appearance while using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap version 5.2 on my website and try to get rid of the arrows in a number input field. Therefore i copied the following code to my css file:

```
/* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Firefox TODO: why does this not work? */
input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield !important;
}
```

Which works perfectly fine in Chrome but has no effect in Firefox. The inspector shows the following attributes:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

which overwrite each other. To get the desired behaviour I have to remove the line

```
appearance: none;
```

and than change the second line to

```
-moz-appearance: textfield;
```

How can I achieve this in my css file?

Comment: I tried your code on my laptop, which works as expected. (With Bootstrap 5.0 loaded) You might want to check other places in your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The problem was at the end, that my old css file was cached in the browser...